# How can I print out the value of each key in a hash represented by *'s?

Tags: ruby, for-loop, hash

Here is my code:

```
class String
  def frequency
    chars.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |char, h|
      h["#{char.upcase}:"] += 1 if char[/[[:alpha:]]/]
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried breaking it down in smaller bit's of code, such as using a .times do loop but I couldn't figure it out

for example:

```
str = "\*"
h["A:"] = count('a').times do
str
end
```

Comment: Not clear to me.. what is the input string? what's the issue.

Comment: This question does need sample input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like:

```
counts = 'aassssvvvvv'.frequency
counts.each{|key,count| puts key + '*'*count}

# A:**
# S:****
# V:*****

Or if you want to change the key you can do:

counts.each{|key,amount| counts[key] = '*'*amount}
```

Comment: You so smart and sexy.

Comment: #frequency does not appear to be in base Ruby.  Is it a Rails extension?

Comment: `frequency` is a function that OP added to the String class, see the original question.